Error initializing Zoom SDK Error= 5 (unknown), internalErrorCode=124
I have integrated zoom meeting using react-native-zoom-us package in react native app.
While trying to initialize react native app with zoom sdk, its giving below error.
Error initializing Zoom SDK Error= 5 (unknown), internalErrorCode=124
Versions in package.json-
"jsrsasign": "^11.1.0",
"react-native-zoom-us": "^8.0.1"
import ZoomUs from 'react-native-zoom-us';
import { KJUR } from 'jsrsasign';

useEffect(() => {
       const newToken =  generateSignature();

    // Initialize Zoom SDK (only once when component mounts)
    ZoomUs.initialize({
        jwtToken: newToken,
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log('Zoom SDK initialized...........',res);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error initializing Zoom SDK..........', error);
    });
    
 }, []);

 function generateSignature(role = 0) {
    const iat = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 30; // Issued at time
    const exp = iat + 3600; // Token expiry time (1 hour)
    const oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }; // Header for the JWT
    const sdkKey = 'KEY'; 
    const secret = 'KEY'; 

    // Payload for the JWT
    const oPayload = {
        sdkKey: sdkKey,
        appKey: sdkKey,
        role: role,
        iat: iat,
        exp: exp,
        tokenExp: exp,
        mn: 82177694602
    };

    const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader); // Stringify header
    const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload); // Stringify payload
    // Sign the JWT
    const sdkJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('HS256', sHeader, sPayload, secret);

    return sdkJWT;
}

